# How do I access the Windows Azure management portal from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, azure

I have only Ubuntu and Debian machines in my office. I’ve registered for the Windows Azure platform and tried to enter their [management portal](https://windows.azure.com/default.aspx), but it requires Microsoft Silverlight.

I’ve tried installing the latest Moonlight plugin available for Ubuntu 11.04, but without any success — after I log in I see a blank page and nothing more. (I tried in both Firefox 7.0.1 and Chromium 14.)

Does anyone know how to enter Microsoft Azure’s management portal from Ubuntu 11.04 or any other Linux distro?

Comment: If you were going to use a Microsoft-owned enterprise application, you really should have foreseen this...  Even the intro video on their landing page uses Silverlight.  Unless there is something I don't know (very possible), you may want to look at alternatives.

Comment: Kevin you're being pretty tough, someone new to MS could easily be fooled by the Windows Azure site which could give the impression that MS actually understands node.js and other non-MS web techs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots has happened since this question was asked (and answered). The current portal is HTML5. Silverlight is no longer in use. You should be able to visit the portal from whichever browser (and from whichever OS) you choose.

Also: You can now access nearly 100% of Azure's features through command-line interface. There's PowerShell (Windows-only) and the nodejs-based CLI, which runs on Mac, Linux, and Windows. You can download the CLI from [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/#cmd-line-tools).

Comment: I do not have access to Azure right now, so I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure runs on Microsoft Platforms.  Not being able to access the site on non-microsoft platforms is just the beginning of your problems.  Consider using a VM or dediciated windows machine for development on Azure.